# The path to the image is not correct

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick

```
public function converter(){
        $pdf = "ci.pdf";
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config = array(
                'image_library' => 'imagemagick',
                'library_path' => 'D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16',
                'source_image' => " /theme/assets/pdf".$pdf,
                'new_image' => " /theme/assets/img/a.jpg",
                'maintain_ratio' => true,
                'width' => 980,
                'quality' => '90%',
             );

             $this->image_lib->initialize( $config );

        if (! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
                $error_msg = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                print_r($error_msg);
        }
        else {
                echo "Done";
        }
}
```

Hi friends i'm trying to convert pdf file to jpg but while executing the controller it replies a message .

> The path to the image is not correct. Image processing failed. Please
>   verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path
>   to your image library is correct.

As i'm new to Codeigniter I was not able to achieve the result .could any one help me how to execute this code .

Comment: Try with absolute paths. Relative ones may not work. Also, mayne you need a `/` at `'source_image' => " /theme/assets/pdf HERE ".$pdf,` cause now it will search for `/theme/assets/pdfci.pdf"`

Comment: Are you using a local host? If so you should be re-sizing image in to same directory your codeigniter project is. But out side of the application folder.